# Как сосчитать текст из файла и разбить его по предложениям в массив?

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм, текст

Хочу реализовать алгоритм на Java, который считывает текст из файла, потом присваивает в переменные массива свои предложения.

Например: `Привет, мир! Что делаешь там? Надо бы нам разобраться!`. В массиве будет:

1. `Привет, мир!`,
2. `Что делаешь там?`,
3. `Надо бы нам разобраться!`.

Не получается. Буду рад помощи и предложенным вариантам реализации.

Вот всё, что имею. Да, код не дописан.

```
package com.threelr;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String text = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println(text);

        int kolsym = 0;
        int TextSize = text.length();
        for(int i = 0; i < TextSize-1; i++){
            if(text.charAt(i) == '.' && text.charAt(i+1) == ' ' || text.charAt(i) == '!' && text.charAt(i+1) == ' ' || text.charAt(i) == '?' && text.charAt(i+1) == ' ' ){
                kolsym++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(kolsym);

        String[] arrtext = new String[kolsym+1];

        int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < TextSize-1; i++){
            arrtext[j] += text.charAt(i);
            if (text.charAt(i) == '.'){
                j++;
                //System.out.print(j);
            }
        }

        for(j = 0; j < kolsym; j++){
            for(int i = 1; i < arrtext[j].length(); i++){
                if((((int)arrtext[j].charAt(i) - (int)'0') <= 9) || (((int)arrtext[j].charAt(i) - (int)'0') >=0))
                {
                    //
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а что получается? С учебными задачами тут помогают, только если вы сами что-то попытались сделать и пришли с конкретной проблемой. Выложите ваш код и напишите, что не получается.

Comment: Как бы Виктор прав... Здесь не форум милосердия. Задача Ваша и вы должны ее хоть как-то попытаться решить. Если у вас совсем нет идей, то это не сюда. Но подсказка имеет место быть...Чтобы разбить строчную перемненную на массив существует метод split. Окончание строки обозначают определенные знаки препинания вроде точки вопросительного и восклицательного знаков. И этих самых знаков исчерпывающий список. Вот и думайте... Предлложите реализацию - мы поможем ее откорректировать, если это потребуется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю как-то так, можно решить эту задачу:

```
String str = "Привет, мир! Что делаешь там?? Надо бы нам разобраться!";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[^.!?]+[.!?]").matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group().trim());
}
```

Вывод:

> Привет, мир!
>   Что делаешь там?
>   Надо бы нам разобраться!

Answer (score 0):

Заменяете все точки, восклицательные и вопросительные знаки на тот же знак но, например, с переходом на новую.строку, далее режете построчно строку в массив

```
String[] sentences = input.replace(". ", ".\n").replace("! ", "!\n").replace("? ", "?\n").split("\n");
```

Comment: Или так:  `input.split("\\.|\\!|\\?")`

Comment: @lampa, регулярки? Ох я до сих пор с ними не дружу)

Comment: @lampa - это не будет работать должным образом, ко всему, ему же нужно еще и знаки оставлять, вопрос читаем. Ваша регулярка, этого не умеет, ко всему, что если вдруг добавится еще  один знак `??` и будет 2 вопроса и у вас образуется пустота.